# flexbox rendering different in chrome and firefox

Tags: flexbox

I am creating a simple movie card layout using flexbox and I am having an issue getting my css to render the same in Chrome as it does in Firefox.

This is the correct rendering in Firefox:
[image]

This is the rending in Chrome:
[image]

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  heading: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: san-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
}

.movie-list__container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movie-card__item {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;

  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movie-card__content {
  margin: 0 10px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.movie-card__options {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
}

.movie-card__left {
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 0 1 155px;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  display: flex;
}

.movie-card__right {
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1 1;
  
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movie-card__poster {
  margin: 5px;
}

.movie-card__poster > img {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.movie-card__date {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.movie-card__runtime {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.movie-card__genre {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.genre-item {
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #263137;
  display: inline-block;
}

.movie-card__controls {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.moive-card__header {
  flex: 0 0;
  display: flex;
}

.movie_card__title {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.movie_card__mpaa-rating {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main>
 <div class="movie-list__container">
  <div class="movie-card__item">
    <div class="movie-card__controls">
          ...
    </div>
    <div class="movie-card__content">
      <div class="movie-card__left">
        <div class="movie-card__poster">
          <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154//x1txcDXkcM65gl7w20PwYSxAYah.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="movie-card__runtime">
          95 minutes
        </div>
        <div class="movie-card__date">
          June 06 2018
        </div>
        <div class="movie-card__genre">
          <span class="genre-item">Horror</span>
          <span class="genre-item">Comedy</span>
          <span class="genre-item">Action</span>
          <span class="genre-item">Drama</span>
          <span class="genre-item">Adventure</span>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie-card__right">
        <div class="moive-card__header">
          <div class="movie_card__title">
           The Incredibles 2
          </div>
          <div class="movie_card__mpaa-rating">
            PG
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="movie-card__overview">
          A family of undercover superheroes, while trying to live the quiet suburban life, are forced into action to save the world.
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="movie-card__options">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</main>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ejBOmz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try this

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
  * {
  margin: 0;
  heading: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: san-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
}

.movie-list__container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movie-card__item {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.12), 0 5px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.24);
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;

  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movie-card__content {
  margin: 0 10px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.movie-card__options {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
}

.movie-card__left {
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 0 1 155px;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

  display: flex;
}

.movie-card__right {
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1 1;

  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movie-card__poster {
  margin: 5px;
}

.movie-card__poster > img {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.12);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.movie-card__date {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.movie-card__runtime {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.movie-card__genre {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.genre-item {
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #263137;
  display: inline-block;
}

.movie-card__controls {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.moive-card__header {
  display: flex;
}

.movie_card__title {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.movie_card__mpaa-rating {
  margin: 5px;
}
</style>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="movie-list__container">
         <div class="movie-card__item">
           <div class="movie-card__controls">
                 ...
           </div>
           <div class="movie-card__content">
             <div class="movie-card__left">
               <div class="movie-card__poster">
                 <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154//x1txcDXkcM65gl7w20PwYSxAYah.jpg" />
               </div>
               <div class="movie-card__runtime">
                 95 minutes
               </div>
               <div class="movie-card__date">
                 June 06 2018
               </div>
               <div class="movie-card__genre">
                 <span class="genre-item">Horror</span>
                 <span class="genre-item">Comedy</span>
                 <span class="genre-item">Action</span>
                 <span class="genre-item">Drama</span>
                 <span class="genre-item">Adventure</span>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div class="movie-card__right">
               <div class="moive-card__header">
                 <div class="movie_card__title">
                  The Incredibles 2
                 </div>
                 <div class="movie_card__mpaa-rating">
                   PG
                 </div>
               </div>
               <div class="movie-card__overview">
                 A family of undercover superheroes, while trying to live the quiet suburban life, are forced into action to save the world.
               </div>

             </div>
           </div>
           <div class="movie-card__options">
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
       </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove    `flex: 0 0;` from `.moive-card__header`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: san-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: black;
}

.movie-list__container {
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movie-card__item {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 5px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  margin: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 40px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movie-card__content {
  margin: 0 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.movie-card__options {
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
}

.movie-card__left {
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 0 1 155px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
}

.movie-card__right {
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.movie-card__poster {
  margin: 5px;
}

.movie-card__poster>img {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.movie-card__date {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.movie-card__runtime {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 2px 10px;
}

.movie-card__genre {
  padding-top: 5px;
}

.genre-item {
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 2px;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #FFF;
  background-color: #263137;
  display: inline-block;
}

.movie-card__controls {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 40px;
  align-self: flex-end;
}

.moive-card__header {
  display: flex;
}

.movie_card__title {
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.movie_card__mpaa-rating {
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="movie-list__container">
    <div class="movie-card__item">
      <div class="movie-card__controls">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="movie-card__content">
        <div class="movie-card__left">
          <div class="movie-card__poster">
            <img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w154//x1txcDXkcM65gl7w20PwYSxAYah.jpg" />
          </div>
          <div class="movie-card__runtime">
            95 minutes
          </div>
          <div class="movie-card__date">
            June 06 2018
          </div>
          <div class="movie-card__genre">
            <span class="genre-item">Horror</span>
            <span class="genre-item">Comedy</span>
            <span class="genre-item">Action</span>
            <span class="genre-item">Drama</span>
            <span class="genre-item">Adventure</span>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="movie-card__right">
          <div class="moive-card__header">
            <div class="movie_card__title">
              The Incredibles 2
            </div>
            <div class="movie_card__mpaa-rating">
              PG
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="movie-card__overview">
            A family of undercover superheroes, while trying to live the quiet suburban life, are forced into action to save the world.
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="movie-card__options">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```